Davinci or Premiere or After Effect. Tag then count the tags
I have videos of hundreds of people walking from right to left. They're not perfectly in a line, but it's quite sparse enough. I'd like to draw a tag on each of their head and count them. How much of it can be automated? Basically, the method I'm thinking about is something like:

Do a face recognition when a person enter the screen.
Put a tag (i.e. draw a physical red rectangle on the head). Step 1 and 2 might have to be done with multiple passes.
Count the tag when a person exit the screen (i.e. count the rectangle).

I have Davinci, but can access After Effects or Premiere if necessary. Thanks.

I think this kind of thing is more commonly done using Python and OpenCV, rather than video editing tools. I don't know of a plugin or process that allows you to continuously track multiple heads in After Effects, although if someone did manage to integrate the code from something like this:
https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-project-real-time-human-detection-counting/
into AE or Premiere, I could see that it could be useful for security & forensics work.
